# buji-pac4j integartion with Apache Shiro and identityServer3

Tags: shiro, identityserver3

I am trying to learn integration of buji-pac4j. I already tried demo version which is provided on following URL https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo but it is seem to be working for me partially. (there is some issue from ops side to give me correct call back url).

So far I can notice handshake is happening using demo code.

I’m now trying other way as it is been provided in the documentation that is **client**.

As per documentation:
A Client represents an authentication mechanism. It performs the login process and returns (if successful) a user profile.

My class has now following details

```
OidcConfiguration oidcConfiguration = new OidcConfiguration();
oidcConfiguration.setClientId("someClientIDString");
oidcConfiguration.setSecret("someClientSecretString");
oidcConfiguration.setDiscoveryURI("https://development.domainName.com/projectName/idp/.well-known/openid-configuration");
oidcConfiguration.setScope("openid email hrauser hrainfo");
oidcConfiguration.setCallbackUrl("http://localhost:8080/callback"); 

OidcClient oidcClient = new OidcClient(oidcConfiguration);
Config config = new Config(oidcClient);
config.addAuthorizer("admin", new RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer("ROLE_ADMIN"));
OidcAuthenticator OidcAuthenticator = new  OidcAuthenticator(oidcConfiguration);
```

Above is mostly setting variable in the class,
What am not able to figure is out how above will actually go and talk to openID server.

What all part I am missing.

I am going through the documentation provided on https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j but it is not clear to me on the flow.

Any kind of help or direction will be appreciated.

PS: I am quite new in this area so request to bear with me.

Comment: any updates, Sourav?

Comment: @jbu, Our requirement got changed so I hold my work in this front.